# How to log stack trace error when ConnectionMultiplexer fails to connect?

Tags: c#, .net-core, stackexchange.redis

I have this code

```
private ILogger logger;
.
.
.
try
{
    redisClient = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    logger.LogError(ex, ex.toString());
    redisClient = null;
    return;
}
```

We intended that if it failed to connect, we wanted to log the stack trace error. But it looks like that won't really cause and exception.
it would just have *redisClient.IsConnected* return false

Is there a way to log stack trace or helful messsage why it failed to connect? This is something we had in mind?

```
private ILogger logger;
.
.
.
var redisClient = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(connectionString);
if(!redisClient.IsConnected)
{
    logger.LogError(redisClient.StackTraceError);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood u now.

there is an event in `ConnectionMultiplexer`. that event is called `ConnectionFailed`

you dont need the try catch. you can do something like this :

```
redisClient.ConnectionFailed += (sender, args) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection failed: " + args.Exception.Message);
};
```

Plus you can missaround with the `args` for extra details

Hope that helps